# the procedure is executed in GUI but the job on webside is not finished

Tags: dolphindb

the procedure is executed in GUI but the job on webside is not finished

why?

code in DolphinDB as below

```py
ts=<select * from loadTable("dfs://Quotes",`Quotes)>
ds=repartitionDS(ts,`Date,RANGE,2021.01.01..2021.01.31)
def WriteDS(data){
    tse=loadTable("dfs://QuotesTSE",`QuotesTSE)
    tfe=loadTable("dfs://QuotesTFE",`QuotesTFE)
    tse.append!(select * from data where Code < `99999)
    tfe.append!(select * from data where Code > `99999)
}
mr(ds,WriteDS,,,false)
```

Answer (score 0):

The connection of client is abnormal because the task takes too long time to execute. It is recommended to execute the long-time task in the background by invoking the function submitJob(). The GUI won’t be blocked in this case.